# delete the beginning of a string till a character found

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
const string ="{* * test * { * username: {{username}} * } }";
```

And i want to have in the end something like this :

```
 "{\n\t\"username\": \"{{username}}\" \n}"
```

I'm trying to delete the first part of the string till the character `"{"` is found. The first one should be ignored of course.

Here is the code that i'm trying :

```
const deleteFirstLastCharacter = string.substr(1).slice(0, -1);
const deleteFirstPart = deleteFirstLastCharacter.split("* * test *").pop();
const replace = deleteFirstPart.replace(/\*/g, "\n\t");
```

The output i get :

```
 { 
         username: {{username}} 
         }
```

The output i want :
In order to have it seen like this :

```
{
        "username": "{{username}}" 
}
```

Comment: Is regex allowed?

Comment: I tried doing it with regex but i couldn't

Comment: Will add regex answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Regex if the syntax doesn't change:

```
.* \{ \* ([^:]+): ([^ ]+) \* } }
```

The first `.*` is to match `{* * test *`.
The rest is to capture the name of the field (username) and then its value, following by the star and closing curly brackets.

When it's a match, you could just replace it with:

```
{\n\t"$1": "$2"\n}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
{
    "username": "{{username}}"
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const string = "{* * test * { * username: {{username}} * } }";
let output = string.replace(/.* \{ \* ([^:]+): ([^ ]+) \* } }/, '{\n\t"$1": "$2"\n}')
console.log(output)
```

Try this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/FbJzRE/1

Comment: actually it worked, but here it's like we're forcing our string to be only two elements. Since the string may change and have other elements.

Comment: It will be really useful to OP and future readers if you create a snippet. They can tweak the regex and test things on their own. If you don't know how to create one: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/3082296)

Comment: That's why I said if the syntax doesn't change a lot, otherwise, update your question and maybe I can tweak the regex. @adiga Thank you for the snippet, I didn't know how to create them until now!

Comment: @Haytam i just updated my question with the original one... in the substitution part can't it be a n groupe?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need some kind of parser for that, as there are nested "fields". Does this syntax have a name? Maybe you can find a library for it.

Comment: I don't actually know, i just get this string generated

Answer (score 1):

Let me just add a solution without regex. Your problem was that you need different order of \n and \t in the two cases of { and } so it will not work with one single replace as you tried.

Try:

```
"{* * test * { * username: {{username}} * } }"
  .substr(1)
  .slice(0, -1)
  .split("* * test *")
  .pop()
  .replace(" { *","{\n\t")
  .replace("* } ", "\t\n}");
```